# Unable to format USB flash

Tags: usb, disk-utility, disk-format

I am trying to format my USB flash in ExFAT format to make it work on both Mac and Win devices. But I am unable to format my USB flash because I am getting an error when trying to format it via `diskutil`.

1) Check our external device in disks list:
[image]

2) Format:
[image]

According to the internet answers, I have tried to boot in safe mode and format USB flash then - but also got 'could not open device' error.

Can somebody help me with this?

P.S. Result of execution command from the question comment:
[image]

Comment: @Allan got this: `test1 does not appear to be a valid volume name for its file system`

Comment: @Allan I have tried uppercase name and result still the same. (but also new question appeared, not sure if it's useful)

Comment: Try unmounting the disk (`sudo diskutil unmountDisk disk2`) and then trying the command again.

Comment: @Allan  thanks , but the result still the same - 'could not open ...'. It seems to be simpler find device with Win and format disk there. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Macs cannot format NTFS drives because they can only read NTFS formatted drives. But if you badly want to format it to Exfat you could use a windows computer to format it to Exfat or install a third party app to format you NTFS drive.

Comment: macOS cannot natively read/write NTFS *partitions*.  There's nothing preventing you from reformatting a partition *from* NTFS to something that macOS can work with like ExFAT or FAT32

Answer (score 0):

I know you like the terminal, so do I. but have you tried this using Disk Utility? I just now took a 4 GB flashdrive and connected it to my machine. I then ran Disk Utility and it worked fine. After I selected my flashdrive, which appeared in a box on the left side of the Disk Utilities pane, I selected to erase drive. There were several options for formatting the disk including MS-DOS (FAT) and ExFat. Disk Utility is located in the Applications/Utilities folder.